# The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'app2.user', but app 'app2' doesn't provide model 'user'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a custom-made User model in **Django**. My app name is `app2`.

My `models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_Employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Inspector = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_IndustryOwner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    extraField = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

I have already put `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app2.User'` in my `settings.py`.

In `admin.py`:

```
admin.site.register(User)
admin.site.register(Employee)
```

Now when I try to migrate I get the following error:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, app2, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 190, in handle
    pre_migrate_apps = pre_migrate_state.apps
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 209, in apps
    return StateApps(self.real_apps, self.models)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 279, in __init__
    raise ValueError("\n".join(error.msg for error in errors))
ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'app2.user', but app 'app2' doesn't provide model 'user'.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: seems like a typo, **`User`** instead of `user`?

Comment: sorry, I can't understand. Where?